# Facebook dont get images from my website metadata correctly when sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have set Facebook metadata to let Facebook get the right data when sharing. But i am having troubles with the images. I have used the url linter tool from Facebook , but i dont know where is the error:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.agendaburgos.com%2Fagenda%2Ffiesta-curpillos-parral.aspx 
The warning it shows is this:
The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input property =>content pairs that were not seen in the parsed result: og:image:url => http://www.agendaburgos.com/Imagen.ashx?url=uploads%5ceventos%5cfiestas-del-curpillos-en-el-parral_5417.jpg&h=200&estirar=true

The link from og:image is right, where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It appears if the Facebook Debug Tool doesn't like the URL to your image. You are using a script to generate a resized version of the uploaded image. Try referencing the original image in your `og:image` tag and see if it helps:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.agendaburgos.com/uploads/eventos/fiestas-del-curpillos-en-el-parral_5417.jpg" />
```

Remember to scrape the page again to update Facebook's cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you're getting this warning may be due to the way you are building the image URL using an ASHX handler.

Don't bother with the dynamic resize. Facebook will handle that once they get the image. Just send your image at full resolution to Facebook.

You also have a problem that you aren't explicitly defining an og:description tag. If you can, you should repeat your description tag as og:description.

Comment: I used to do this, but facebook has limitations on the width and height. Many other pages on the site use this resizing and Facebook gets the images right.